# Error: Exception NSException * "the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElement

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift5

Can anybody help me to point out where I am getting wrong here? My app crashes with the following error:

```
Thread 1: 

Exception: "the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,
<NSIndexPath: 0x8180a74d626573ba> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) 
was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil 

(<UICollectionReusableView: 0x7fd9fbecc400; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000028c7f60>>)"
```

Here is the method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath:
            IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
            
            guard kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter else {
                // footer
            return UICollectionReusableView()
            }
            
            if indexPath.section == 1 {
                // tabs header
                let tabControlHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                                                                                       withReuseIdentifier: ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView.identifier,
                                                                                       for: indexPath) as! ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView
                return tabControlHeader
    
            }
            
            let profileHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                                                                                withReuseIdentifier: ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView.identifier,
                                                                                for: indexPath) as! ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView
            return profileHeader
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by changing

```
guard kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter else {
                // footer
            return UICollectionReusableView()
            }
```

to

```
guard kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader else {
                // footer
            return UICollectionReusableView()
            }
```

Also make sure in `Main.storyboard` you have *Inherit Module From Target* is checked in every `View Controller`

Answer (score 0):

The error reads better like this

```
the view returned from 
-collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath
was 

either
not retrieved by calling 
-dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: 

or 
is nil
```

The view the following code is returning is the issue.

```
return UICollectionReusableView()
```

Put a breakpoint inside `guard else` early return block. Decide whether you want to return a `dequeued` header or footer from there.

You have to return a header / footer that was instantiated using `collectionView.dequeueXXX` call and not something you created yourself.